# vue.js dropdown of autocomplete doesn't render when inside of a v-for

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, dropdown, visual-studio-2022, v-for

[image: Screenshot of page]

New to vue, and this particular project is using vue 2.6.10.

We have a proprietary control that we use which is basically a network user lookup.

I came on to this already established project. It is built using template.html files and their respective .js files.

I have this particular template file where I need a v-for with my lookup control inside. I cannot get the dropdown to render when it is inside of the v-for. If I take out the v-for and hardcode the controls (as a test), the lookup dropdowns render fine.

Please see my two versions of the code, the hardcoded one which works, and the v-for version that does not render my dropdown after a search by name.

One thing I have noticed that is a difference between the 2 versions, is that when I inspect my elements, I see that when the dropdown does render properly, the input control has ui-autocomplete-input as part of the class and also has autocomplete="off". When the control does not work as expected, those two items don't exist in the input control.

Working version:

```
<template id="email-template">
    <div class="container border col-md-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <tabs style="padding-top:10px;">
            <tab title="Task Summary">
                <table class="table userForm"> <!--class userForm must be here for nedLookup!!-->
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email Groups</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="col-md-5">
                                            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%">Group1 Members</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">AutoInclude</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Delete</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>user1@test.com</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;'>
                                                            <label class="label" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" style='margin-left: 0' checked>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;' class='trash-icon'>
                                                            <i class='fa fa-trash' style='margin-left: 0'></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>user2@test.com</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;'>
                                                            <label class="label" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;' class='trash-icon'>
                                                            <i class='fa fa-trash' style='margin-left: 0'></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr><td colspan="3"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> AutoInclude Entire Group</label></td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">
                                            <input type="text" :id="Group1_userLookup"
                                                   :name="Group1_userLookup" value=""
                                                   class="nedLookup form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Search User by Last Name, FirstName" />
                                            <!--<input id="userLookupEmail" type="hidden" data-ned="Email" />-->
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addUserToGroup()" role="button">
                                                Add User to Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-1">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveGroup()" role="button">
                                                Save Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="col-md-5">
                                            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%">Group2 Members</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">AutoInclude</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Delete</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>user3@test.com</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;'>
                                                            <label class="label" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;' class='trash-icon'>
                                                            <i class='fa fa-trash' style='margin-left: 0'></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr><td colspan="3"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> AutoInclude Entire Group</label></td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">
                                            <input type="text" :id="Group2_userLookup"
                                                   :name="Group2_userLookup" value=""
                                                   class="nedLookup form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Search User by Last Name, FirstName" />
                                            <input id="userLookupEmail" type="hidden" data-ned="Email" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addUserToGroup()" role="button">
                                                Add User to Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-1">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveGroup()" role="button">
                                                Save Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <btn type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addNewEmailGroup" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Email Group </btn>
                </div>

            </tab>

            <!-- Survey Email settings-->
            <tab title="Survey">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Coming Soon</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </tab>

        </tabs>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .emailGroup-header {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .emailGroup-header:hover {
            background-color: #E7E7E7;
        }
</style>
```

Non working version with v-for:

```
<template id="email-template">
    <div class="container border col-md-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <tabs style="padding-top:10px;">
            <tab title="Task Summary">
                <table class="table userForm"> <!--class userForm must be here for nedLookup!!-->
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Email Groups</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="emailGroupMembers in emailGroupMembersAllList">
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">
                                            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%">{{emailGroupMembers.EmailGroup.GroupName}} Members</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">AutoInclude</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Delete</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tr v-for="user in emailGroupMembers.EmailGroup.EmailGroupUsers">
                                                    <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;'>
                                                            <label class="label" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" style='margin-left: 0' checked>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;' class='trash-icon'>
                                                            <i class='fa fa-trash' style='margin-left: 0'></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">
                                            <input type="text" :id="emailGroupMembers.EmailGroup.GroupName + '_userLookup'"
                                                   :name="emailGroupMembers.EmailGroup.GroupName + '_userLookup'" value=""
                                                   class="nedLookup form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Last Name, FirstName" />
                                            <!--<input id="userLookupEmail" type="hidden" data-ned="Email" />-->
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addUserToGroup()" role="button">
                                                Add User to Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveGroup()" role="button">
                                                Save Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <!--<tr>
                            <td>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">
                                            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%">Group2 Members</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">AutoInclude</th>
                                                        <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Delete</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>karrie.klein@saic.com</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;'>
                                                            <label class="label" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                                <input type="checkbox" style='margin-left: 0'>
                                                            </label>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <span style='display: block; text-align: center; padding-top: 0;' class='trash-icon'>
                                                            <i class='fa fa-trash' style='margin-left: 0'></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">
                                            <input type="text" :id="Group2_userLookup"
                                                   :name="Group2_userLookup" value=""
                                                   class="nedLookup form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Last Name, FirstName" />
                                            <input id="userLookupEmail" type="hidden" data-ned="Email" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addUserToGroup()" role="button">
                                                Add User to Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="saveGroup()" role="button">
                                                Save Group
                                            </button>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>-->

                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <btn type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="addNewEmailGroup" role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Email Group </btn>
                </div>

            </tab>

            <!-- Survey Email settings-->
            <tab title="Survey">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Coming Soon</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </tab>

        </tabs>
    </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .emailGroup-header {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .emailGroup-header:hover {
            background-color: #E7E7E7;
        }
</style>
```

email.js file:

```
var emailPanel = Vue.component('email-panel', {
    props: {
    //    id: {
    //        type: Number,
    //    },
    //    emailGroupMembersAllList: {
    //        type: Object
    //    },
    //    autoIncludeEmails: {
    //        type: Object
    //    },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            opened: [],
            emailGroupMembersAllList: [],
        }
    },
    template: '#email-template',
    beforeMount() {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handlerClose);
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.handlerClose);
    },
    mounted() {
        $(".userForm").nedLookup();

        this.getEmails();
    },
    computed: {
    },
    methods: {
        getEmails() {
            var vm = this;

            //go get emails (including current user of this page) and fill GroupLists/to/cc/Subject
            this.getTaskSummaryEmails()
                .then(data => {
                    vm.emailGroupMembersAllList = data.EmailGroupMembersAllList;
                    vm.autoIncludeEmails = data.AutoIncludeEmails;
                    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        async getTaskSummaryEmails() {
            try {
                let resp;
                resp = await axios.get(`/api/task/email`);
                return resp.data;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                this.$toasted.show("There was an error retrieving the email groups", { type: "error", duration: 3000 })
            }
        },
        addNewEmailGroup() {
        },

        toggleEmailGroup(id) {
            const index = this.opened.indexOf(id);
            if (index > -1) {
                this.opened.splice(index, 1)
            } else {
                this.opened.push(id)
            }
        },

        tabChanged() {
            if (this.$toasted != null) {
                this.$toasted.clear();
            }
        },

        handlerClose(e) {
            if (this.$toasted != null) {
                this.$toasted.clear();
            }
        },
    }
})
```

I have searched and not found anything matching my particular issue with this old version of vue.js

I have found suggestions regarding using the :key. I am not moving things around, so I don't believe I need the :key, but I tried it anyway to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just going back to basics, I added an eventhandler for an outer static element and that solved the issue.

```
    mounted() {
    this.getEmails();

    //Creating event delegate here for our dynamically added nedLookups
    //have to add event listener to element that is already in the DOM and that contains our nedLookup
    document.getElementById("emailGroupsTable").addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
        if (e.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') { //this is one of the nedLookup elements
            $(".userForm").nedLookup();
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `key` on this line:

```js
<tr v-for="emailGroupMembers in emailGroupMembersAllList">
```

Try:

```js
<tr v-for="(emailGroupMembers, index) in emailGroupMembersAllList" :key="index">
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion; however, adding the key makes no difference for me.